# connecting datetimepicker to angularjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I need to create one input field with date and time using angular + bootstrap.
I found this [datetime picker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) it looks excatly i need - date and time in one field, and blocking user wrong editions.
I writed a directive, datepickers started, but it changes the view and the model doesn't changes... I also tried onSelect, but nothing happens too

```
<div class="container container-fluid" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
2+2={{2+2}}, var1={{var1}}
    <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate name="form" ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="well">
        <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng_model="var1">
            <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text" id="input1" name="input1" ng_model="var1"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

js

```
var project = angular.module('project',['ui.bootstrap']);

project.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function(){
                element.datetimepicker({
                    dateFormat:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
                    language: 'pt-BR',
                    onSelect:function (date) {
                        //alert('zz');
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});

project.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$rootScope',  function(scope, rootScope){

    scope.var1="123";

}]);
```

How to fix it? to make connection?

Comment: Can you post your example in Fiddle?

Comment: somehow it is not working in jsfiddle(

Comment: i dont understand how to move it to jsfiddle, ill try to add max code there

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sLmyz/ i copied all code included all files bu date dialog not appears (  here is screenshot of both files  http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/8231/9xbp.png

Comment: and screen of action date in input changed but var1 steel old value http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/3882/5enm.png

Comment: This doesn't explicitly answer your question; but the UI Bootstrap project includes some directives for a DatePicker.

Comment: they separate date and time( and also they allow user to type wrong chars, while i need 1 field with input filtering

Comment: There is also another datetimepicker directive for angular that can be found at https://github.com/zhaber/datetimepicker

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the problems are:

1. change `ng_model`per `ng-model` in the `div id=date` element;
2. remove `ng_model` from the `input` element and implement `ngModelCtrl.$render` function in order to render model changes to the element
3. as per the [component docs](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#api):

> The only event exposed is ‘changeDate’, which will expose ‘date’ and ‘localDate’ properties on the event object

So you need to handle the change event other ways, look:

```
element.datetimepicker({
  dateFormat:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
    language: 'pt-BR'
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
    scope.$apply();
  });
```

Here is a [working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZ6QyrLNajRgIMSlUqsg?p=preview).

Some additional tips:

1. as said before, remove the internal `ng-model` and implement `ngModelCtrl.$render` to handle model changes
2. use the `template` property in order to encapsulate the internal elements of the component

A pretty simple example of using $render:

```
var picker = element.data('datetimepicker');

ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
  if (ngModelCtrl.$modelValue) {
    picker.setLocalDate(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue);
  } else {
    picker.setLocalDate(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! "and implement ngModelCtrl.$render to handle model changes" what do you mean? Does "ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);" not enough? Actualy i dont understand the way new value comes to input ( we setted new value to div(it's the div who has directive 'datetimez') not input so how does date value jumped to input? It's because of class="input-append"? it's bootstrap who do this value move?

Comment: Answering both your questions, you use `$setViewValue` to update the model upon a change in the view. And you use `$render` to update the view when there is a change in the model. Take a look in [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController#methods). Will add a small example to the answer.

Comment: Just added a example of how to implement the `ngModelCtrl.$render` function.

Comment: ok, i understand that we setted ViewValue for DIV element but how this value comes to input?? Input has no ngModel atribute at all... They are connected somehow via css - id="input1" and class="input-append"? and also a question about data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" attribute of input. If we hardcoded dateFormat:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' in out derictive then it will be ignored?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but you could always use this one

[Bootstrap-ui/datetime-picker](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker) it uses the datepicker and timepicker from bootstrap-ui without using jquery or moment.js

Answer (score 1):

CaioToOn solution is pretty nice. But on top of that it seems that there is "official" wrapper now on following address:

https://gist.github.com/derfbn/73350e5f8eb92c3967d7

Comment: You should never use JQuery with Angular!