# convert date formats using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have date picker, i want to convert date format to '2014/12/03(i.e yyyy/mm/dd)'.

date format is **dd/mm/yyyy** in the text field, while focusout need to change the date format to **yyyy/mm/dd**(passing the date value to server)

```
<div for="dtp_input2" class="input-group date form_date"  data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-ng-model="systemdate"  date-picker>
   <input type="text" id="systemdate" name="systemdate" class="form-control input-append inputDatepicker"  placeholder="Date" data-ng-model="systemdate" data-ng-blur="getBatchNumbers()" format-date/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar add-on"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" />
```

I tried to convert inside controller,

```
console.log($scope.systemdate); //2014-03-12
var date = $filter('date')($scope.systemdate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

but 'date' variable also  converting in same format i.e 2014-03-12

Comment: Try this:
var date = $filter('date')($scope.systemdate, "yyyy/MM/dd");

Comment: You can momentJS lib for it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the date picker ? How does it set the systemdate? From your html snippiet it looks like you are setting systemdate with an input element + ng-model.? For a simple approach of formatting the input text as a date, see https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-date

Comment: Also, look here for a nice solution on how to wrap a datepicker in an AngularJS directive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728585/how-to-wrap-the-datetimepicker-js-into-angularjs-directive#27365053 (while taking care of date format)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below link

http://plnkr.co/edit/J6ATK1ozJFxZQFSXaUNy?p=preview

HTML

```
Enter Date : <input type="text" placeholder='dd/mm/yyyy' onblur='changeFormat()' id='ipdate'/>
```

JS

```
var changeFormat = function (ipdate) {
  var d = document.getElementById('ipdate').value;
  d = d.split("/");
  d.reverse();
  document.getElementById('formattedDate').innerHTML = d[0]+'/'+d[1]+'/'+d[2];
}
```