# Storing Date input values on Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-filters

So this is how my code looks like

```
cropref.child(mycrop.name).push({
                          cropname:mycrop.name,
                          croplocation:mycrop.location,
                          cropplantdate:mycrop.plantdate.toString(),
                          cropharvestdate:mycrop.harvestdate.toString(),         
                  })
```

`mycrop.harvestdate` and `mycrop.plantdate` are both date inputs from my html

```
<input type="date" ng-model='mycrop.harvestdate'>

<input type="date" ng-model='mycrop.harvestdate'>
```

to be able to put the data on my Firebase database , I need to convert it first into string

```
cropplantdate:mycrop.plantdate.toString(),
```

but the data on my Firebase database includes time and timezone

sample data

```
Sat Dec 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
```

so once I call the data from my database, I can't filter it since it's not a date anymore but a string. 
How do I solve this problem so that I can filter date (which is converted to string) stored inside my database

Comment: If you insist on storing dates as strings, store them in a format that is chronological in lexicographical order. E.g. `2016-11-27T17:01:19`. But better yet: simply store the timestamp as milliseconds since the epoch. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957249/storing-dates-with-angular-and-firebase/34957326#34957326

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options

1) Store the date in a more generic, but human readable format, so right now would be Sunday November 27 at 09:13:38

```
20161127091338
```

2) Store the date as a unix timestamp (in milliseconds) using

```
(new Date).getTime() / 1000
```

There are a lot of variants to #2 so do some research to see which is best for your use case.

You can save either answer as a string but #1 would be more easily searchable since queries wouldn't require any kind of conversions -  to see todays events

```
queryStartingAt("20161127") and queryEndingAt("20161127")
```

Comment: i like the number one but how do i convert it back to date format sir ? like mm/dd/yyyy again

Comment: @Nevin There are a bunch of ways to convert dates but check this question and answer out [Angular Date Converstion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493843/convert-date-formats-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date first in your Format. You can use SimpleDateFormatFormat for that.

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Now you can easily format your date to this format

```
String mynewdate = sdf.format(mycrop.plantdate.getTime());
```

The Output for today would be:

```
2016-11-27
```

Of course you can reverse that back to a Calendar. I do it this way:

```
 public static Calendar fromStringtoCalendar(String datestring){
    int year =  Integer.valueOf(datestring.substring(0, 4));
    int month =  Integer.valueOf(datestring.substring(5, 7)) -1;
    int day =  Integer.valueOf(datestring.substring(8, 10));
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);
    return calendar;
}
```

Comment: i think the the code is used for android ? i'm using web btw

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I made a mistake there.