# Save and restore date to firebase?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a small problem with firebase and angular 2.

I try to save a user into the firebase database. Everythings works good, but the date isnt stored.

```
let now: Date = new Date();
let premiumExpireDate: Date = new Date();
premiumExpireDate.setDate(premiumExpireDate.getDate()+14);

// Insert data on our database using AngularFire.
this.angularfire.database.object('/accounts/' + userId).set({
    name: name, // works well
    dateUpdated: now, // isnt stored
    premiumExpireDate: premiumExpireDate // isnt stored too
}).then(() => {
    ...
});
```

Do you have a idea, how to save and also restore a data to and from firebase?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Firebase Database stores JSON data and `Date` is not a JSON type. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829336/storing-date-input-values-on-firebase for options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't save a date object. You'll have to convert it to timestamp

```
this.angularfire.database.object('/accounts/' + userId).set({
    name: name, // works well
    dateUpdated: now.getTime(), // isnt stored
    premiumExpireDate: premiumExpireDate.getTime() // isnt stored too
}).then(() => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Ah, thats easy. Whats the best way to convert this back to a Date? Maybe new Date(timestamp)? Or something else? Thanks a lot!