# Looking up specific data in list of push id's firebase/angularfire2/ionic

Tags: list, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to figure out how you are supposed to retrieve data using `firebase`s push id system. I know that when I am going to get the data, I will only know what the `date` property is (I am making a booking app)...when I look up the data how am I supposed to know the push id that corresponds to the input data. The structure looks like this...I'm not sure how I am supposed to know which pushid the `date` I want is saved under.

[image]

Again, how do I know which push id is for which set of data?

Comment: Please don't store the date as a string in that format. While that is a reasonable display format (for certain locale) it is pretty much useless for anything else. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216858/firebase-query-by-date-string/38226376#38226376 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829336/storing-date-input-values-on-firebase

Comment: Once you fix that, you can query for the nodes with a specific date. See https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md