# Good datetime picker with the following requirements

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I've tried out a bunch of datetime pickers but I haven't found one that works 100% percent yet.

I'm using AngularJS and styling my page with Bootstrap. But I'm using Firefox for development and since it's HTML5 support isn't that great all the Angular solutions haven't been working. All the pure Bootstrap options use JQuery, which I would rather not use if I don't have to. Also, I think this is relevant to Bootstrap, the date is input on a form in a Bootstrap modal, which also causes issues with some of the Bootstrap solutions.

So if anyone can point me to a datetime picker built in AngularJS but without using HTML5 and styled after Bootstrap that would be amazing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "without HTML5", but how about https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker

Comment: That one anly allows you to pick dates, I need date and time.

Comment: Meanwhile I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728585/how-to-wrap-the-datetimepicker-js-into-angularjs-directive, gonna see if it can do what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my answer in case anyone has the same issue:

After trying a lot of pickers I finally used http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/.

But I was only able to get it working after reading a few other questions and answers and I think my problem was that I had a custom [JQuery-UI](https://jqueryui.com) file I was using, and I was not using [Angular Moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment). After I downloaded the complete `jquery-ui` file and added `angular-moment` to my module, the datetime picker worked perfectly. I did not have to do any conversions with the `Date` object and there were no issues with the Bootstrap modal.