# connecting datetimepicker to angularjs with bootstrap v3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm basing this question on a previous question here [connecting datetimepicker to angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482449/connecting-datetimepicker-to-angularjs)
which was answered by a working planker http://plnkr.co/edit/jZ6QyrLNajRgIMSlUqsg?p=preview

I'm trying to use the datetimepicker in angular as the original question illustrates:

```
<div class="container container-fluid" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
2+2={{2+2}}, var1={{var1}}
    <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate name="form" ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="well">
        <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng_model="var1">
            <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text" id="input1" name="input1" ng_model="var1"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap 3 (the working plunker uses version 2) and angular 1.2.13
I forked the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rdmH6RsYk7iYPhUzbY51?p=preview and switched bootstrap files (css and js) with bootstrap3 and switched to angular 1.2.13 and this doesn't work at all. Also, the original plunker used bootstrap combined css, which I'm using the regular one.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to use the `datapicker` that provided by [angular-bootstrap-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), this integrate `datapicker` and some others in it.
The most convenient place is simple to custom some function and dont have to consider dealing with bootstrap.

Comment: I need a timepicker as well. I'm using the datepicker you mentioned in my app but I have a specific flow which requires time entry as well

Comment: angular-bootstrapp-ui also provide a [`timepicker` directives](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap), you can search it at that demo page

Comment: I know, i'm looking for a time and date picker in the same control